# JavaScript Regex to create array of whole words only.

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to split out the whole words out of a string without whitespace or special characters.

So from

```
'(votes + downvotes) / views'
```

I'd like to create an array like the following

```
['votes', 'downvotes, 'views']
```

Have tried the following, but catching the parens and some whitespace.
https://regex101.com/r/yX9iW8/1

Comment: Is it just the string in your example or others as well? Are numbers expected in input? If so, do you want to treat them as "words?"

Comment: Im splitting the numbers and operators into their own arrays with another match.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\W+` to split on all non-word characters

```
'(votes + downvotes) / views'.split(/\W+/g).filter(x => x !== '');
// ["votes", "downvotes", "views"]
```

Or `\w+` to match on all word characters

```
'(votes + downvotes) / views'.match(/\w+/g);
// ["votes", "downvotes", "views"]
```

Comment: Thanks Paul, this worked great. As soon as I can accept an answer I will.

Comment: An even better option would be `.filter(x => x)`

Comment: @RichardHamilton thought about it, decided that I wasn't so comfortable with it in a filter. If you want shorter shorthand, either `Boolean` or `x => !!x` would sit better with me `[2, undefined, 1, 'a', '', false, null].filter(Boolean); // [2, 1, "a"]`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `/\w+/g` as regular expression in combination with [`String#match`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match)

```js
var array = '(votes + downvotes) / views'.match(/\w+/g);
console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very simple...

```
var matches = '(votes + downvotes) / views'.match(/[a-z]+/ig);
```

You must decide for your project what characters make a words, and min-length of word. It can be chars with digits and dash with min-length of 3 characters...

```
[a-z0-9-]{3,}
```

Good luck!